# Como configurar anuncios da mopub?

Tags: android, android-studio, publicidade, anúncio

Quando você instala o plugin do `mopub` no [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/sdk/index.html) você escolhe o tipo de anuncio banner e ele te da todo código para você ir colando no lugar certo.

Você executa funciona certinho aparece no anuncio teste, ai você vai no site e cria o banner pega chave e troca a que esta no programa , ai testei no celular físico e anuncio não aparece, tem mais configuração a fazer?

O erro apareceu no XML:

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code
>   or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
>   java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getWebViewPackageName(WebViewFactory.java:78)
>     at
>   android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getFactoryClass(WebViewFactory.java:132)
>     at
>   android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:101)
>     at
>   android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.getInstance(WebViewDatabase.java:44)
>     at com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView.(MoPubView.java:77)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:809)
>     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385) Copy
>   stack to clipboard

logcat sobre mopub:

> 06-19 14:31:10.973    2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to
>   retrieve GPS location: access appears to be disabled. 06-19
>   14:31:10.983    2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to retrieve
>   network location: access appears to be disabled. 06-19 14:31:11.023
>   2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Loading url:
>   http://ads.mopub.com/m/ad?v=6&id=**Minha.Key**&nv=3.8.0%2Bkit&dn=unknown%2Csdk%2Csdk&bundle=NomeDaPeckage.&z=-0400&o=p&w=480&h=800&sc_a=1.5&mcc=310&mnc=260&iso=us&cn=Android&ct=3&av=1.1&udid=mp_tmpl_advertising_id&dnt=mp_tmpl_do_not_track&mr=1&android_perms_ext_storage=0
>   06-19 14:31:14.583    2319-2390/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to
>   retrieve GPS location: access appears to be disabled. 06-19
>   14:31:14.583    2319-2390/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to retrieve
>   network location: access appears to be disabled. 06-19 14:31:14.653
>   2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage.lamath I/MoPub﹕ Ad failed to load. 06-19
>   14:31:14.653    2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. I/com.mopub﹕ Ad failed to
>   load.

Com chave teste funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que isso tem alguma coisa a ver, no site parece que da para testar, veja a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="NomeDaPeckage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="NomeDaPeckage.Activity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value=" " />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Olá. Poderia, por favor, pesquisar no seu logcat alguma referencia com `MoPub`? Provavelmente, está aparecendo algum erro ao tentar inicializar o seu anúncio

Comment: Se deu algum erro, provavelmente apareceu em seu logcat!

Comment: Este erro é problema de renderização no preview de seu layout. Com seu device conectado, acesse a aba `Android` no rodapé do Android Studio, selecione `logcat` e, no campo de pesquisa, digite `MoPub`. Veja se aparece algo

Comment: não está mais executando, aparece esse erro `06-18 16:10:53.919  13727-13727/system_process E/cutils-trace﹕ Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: @sicachester de uma olhada no pergunta coloquei o que aparece no logcat, engraçado troca a chave pela chave teste funciona .

Comment: @sicachester editei a pergunta adicionei mais uma coisa referente o site, bom Requests (pedidos ) muda o valor mas o restante é 0 impressão clickis

Comment: @sicachester você pode me ajudar?

Comment: você pode incluir seu `AndroidManifest.xml`? Estou suspeitando que seja alguma configuração faltando

Comment: @sicachester já editei a pergunta e `AndroidManifest.xml` está lá

Comment: Provavelmente faltou algum "passo" na configuracao do MoPub. Siga estas instrucoes https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: @sicachester estou usando android studio, o link que você passou não tem para android studio, estou meio perdido nessa configuração, pois quando implementei eu instalei o plugin, ele vai aparecer lá aba, você escolhe o tipo de banner ou tela inteira ai ele já configura, se for só alterar o `androidManifest.xml` tem algumas coisa que fica com erro.

Comment: que são `<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
        <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />`

Comment: e mais ` <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: Tente remover o atributo `screenSize` de todas as `Activity` de seu manifesto e tente novamente

Comment: não funcionou, será que mopub precisa de outra de rede de anuncio vinculado para funcionar.

Comment: @Rodolfo gostaria de saber se a resposta faltou algo ou não funcionou. Poderia me informar?

Comment: realmente não consegui fazer funcionar

Comment: @sicachester poderia me informar se `moPub` é necessário criar uma rede anuncio ou ela tem anuncio próprio?

Answer (score 3):

Ao ler estas mensagens

```
06-19 14:31:10.973    2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to retrieve GPS location: access appears to be disabled.
06-19 14:31:10.983    2319-2319/NomeDaPeckage. D/MoPub﹕ Failed to retrieve network location: access appears to be disabled.
```

O que me faz acreditar que você não liberou o GPS e a REDE para o seu aplicativo, seria necessário isto:

- Declare as seguintes permissões:

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Declare os seguintes "activity":

  ```
  <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
  <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
  <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
  <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
  <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.MMActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
  <activity android:name="com.millennialmedia.android.VideoPlayer" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard" />
  ```

Acredito que `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` já resolve a questão do GPS, mas se ainda acusar o erro `access appears to be disabled.`, então tente a seguinte permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
```

- `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` é baseado na rede de internet
- `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` é baseado no GPS

<sub>**Detalhes em:** https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Getting-Started</sub>

Comment: poderia me informar se `moPub` é necessário criar uma rede anuncio ou ela tem anuncio próprio?

Comment: @Rodolfo não sei lhe informar ao certo, mas acho que você gerencia os anuncios após se cadastrar em https://app.mopub.com/account/register/ então você faz o login https://app.mopub.com/account/login/?next=/dashboard/ - No dashboard você terá o controle e ainda o "analytics" próprio e controle monetário. É provavel que tenha "rede" e que possa cadastrar seus proprios anuncios, mas não tenho certeza. Boa sorte.

Comment: quando cria o anuncio fica assim no Orders `MoPub Demo Order ` acredito para funcionar os anuncio deveria ficar `MoPub Demo Order Marketplace ` mas valeu pelo resposta

Comment: @Rodolfo é este problema vai além do que você perguntou, acho melhor você criar uma nova pergunta voltada ao problema que enfrenta agora.